# Proper way to fill a field/generate a value inside a widget

Tags: python, tkinter

So I've got a Tkinter widget which scrapes a result online. I want it to output a few values to the widget, rather than the Python IDLE console. How would I do that? Would I programmatically/dynamically set a label? Every example I've looked up is how to put content initially into an entry widget, which is not what I want.

Like, for example, say you have a widget box

```
----------
[        ]
[ Search ]
[        ]
[ Output ]
----------
```

I want, whenever I click search, for the output values to display in the output section.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would set a label in the gui. You can dynamically change the label throughout your code using `text=StringVar`. Where `StringVar` is a variable you have and when you change the value of `StringVar`, it changes the value of the label. Also, `StringVar` must be a `tkinter` `stringvar` object.

Answer (score 0):

Sure can. You can set a variable to hold the value of a Tkinter label. With that variable you can call .get() and .set() on it to change it at any time.

Below is a quick example that just updates a label with the current value of time.time()

```
import Tkinter
import time

class DynamicLabelExample(Tkinter.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.pack()
      Tkinter.Button(self, text="Search", command=self.update_output).pack()
      self.output_container = Tkinter.StringVar()
      Tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.output_container).pack()


   def update_output(self):
      self.output_container.set(time.time())

root = Tkinter.Tk()
ex = DynamicLabelExample(root)
root.mainloop()
```

`self.output_container` is our Tkinter StringVar that we manipulate every time we press the button.

[Source](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the contents of a label with the `configure` method. For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Show time", command=self.on_show_time)
        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.button.pack()
        self.label.pack()

    def on_show_time(self):
        self.label.configure(text=time.asctime())

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```